# How do I combine multiple cells into 1. I'm creating a commission leader board for my team and I want it to funnel all of their commission into one

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

[image: Commission Leader board Layout]

Commission stucture:

```
B3 $50  x4
C3 $60  x5
D3 $100  x4
E3 4-$100  x4
F3 4-$120  x4
G3 AAl   0
H3 UG   x3
I4 Boost Up  x3
J4 Add Ons   x1
K4 Accessory Revenue:
0-$1000.01 15%
1000.01-$3000.001 20%
$3000.01-$4000.01 22 and a half
$4000.01-$5000.01 25%
L4 Commission
```

I want all of this to funnel into the Commission so it is easily accessible to them and easily edited for future use. Can this been done and what would the formula be to complete it.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 0):

maybe like (assuming you add up all fields together):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A<>"", (
 (B3:B*4)+(C3:C*5)+(D3:D*4)+(E3:E*4)+(F3:F)+(G3:G*3)+(H3:H*3)+(I3:I*1))+((
 (B3:B*4)+(C3:C*5)+(D3:D*4)+(E3:E*4)+(F3:F)+(G3:G*3)+(H3:H*3)+(I3:I*1))*VLOOKUP(
 (B3:B*4)+(C3:C*5)+(D3:D*4)+(E3:E*4)+(F3:F)+(G3:G*3)+(H3:H*3)+(I3:I*1), 
 {0, 15%; 1000.01, 20%; 3000.01, 22.5%; 4000.01, 25%; 5000.01, 0}, 2)), ))
```

[image: 0]